# Feedme Skip Entry if No Matching Elements on Field

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-feedme

Is there a way on Feedme to not import an entry if it doesn't have a match on a specific field?

> e.g. If there is no entry that it matches up to, don't import it.

Here's the current code I have:

```
Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE, function (FeedProcessEvent $event) {
    $myField=$event->feedData['myfieldname'];
    if ($myField == null){
        $event->element->isValid=false;
    }
});
```

The above processes the data getting loaded in. Here's code for processing data after it's parsed.

```
Event::on(Fields::class, Fields::EVENT_AFTER_PARSE_FIELD, function(FieldEvent $event) {
    if ($event->fieldHandle['merchants'] == null) {
    $event->isValid=false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isValid` should be set on the `$event` variable, not on `$event->element`:

```
Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE, function (FeedProcessEvent $event) {
    $myField=$event->feedData['myfieldname'];
    if ($myField == null){
        $event->isValid=false;
    }
});
```

I haven't tested but looking at the [feed-me source code](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/blob/develop/src/services/Process.php#L420), this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it working, but I'm looking to access the field's in FeedMe. I have a field in FeedMe called "Merchants" but some of imported entries won't get matched up to anything, so I'm trying to stop them being saved if they don't match up.

Comment: Updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

After a lot of tinkering - I finally found out how to check if the field is matching/existing and if nothing matches - Skip adding this element.

```
Event::on(
Process::class, 
Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE, 
function (craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent $event) {
  switch($event->feed['name']){
    case 'offers':

      $merchants = $event->element->merchants;
      if (sizeof($merchants) === 0) {
          $event->isValid=false;
      }
    break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like the only thing that differs from nstCactus' answer is your additional check code?  IMO that doesn't really improve the answer as the key is in the ``$event->isValid`` line which was pointed out in that answer. (You also didn't mention in the question that ``$merchants`` is supposed to be an array?)

Comment: Sure, I've reimbursed the internet points.